# Tocken authentication fails in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I can create user models. But authentication always fails even if there exists such a user with the given credentials

models.py have user creation method as

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

views.py have login/authentication method as

```
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        user = authenticate(
        username=request.data['username'], 
        password=request.data['password'])

        if user:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': UserSerializer(user).data})

        return Response('Invalid username or passwordee', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

settings.py is here

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
}
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Your code has no problem, but it just returns the token which used for authentication not related to authentication step.

Comment: i can't get it. why is it not working then? pls help.

Comment: On token authentication flow, it has two flows. First is generated token, it will required the  user's credentials to create a token. After that, client will use this token to add into headers of each request, then django have a step to verify this token, and return of this step is a user object. Your code is first step. It's ok but maybe youhave something wrong at second step. Could you send your config for drf?

Comment: i am a bit new to Django. what do u mean by config? settings.py?

Comment: Yes, in settings.py file we have REST_FRAMEWORK dictionary for configuration.

Comment: i have added it. pls help @NguyenQuangTrung